# How to load list into another activity's layout?

Tags: android, facebook

I am using this to retreive the text from the facebook of the user when logged in is successful.

```
public void loginSuccess(Facebook facebook) {

            GraphApi graphApi = new GraphApi(facebook);

            User user = new User();
            School school = new School();
            Work work = new Work();
            RestApi rest = new RestApi(facebook);
                List<Status> status;
            try {
             status = rest.getStatus(10); //Retreive 10 user status's

            } catch (EasyFacebookError e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


            startActivity(intentResult);
        }
}
```

As you see i am use the list of status's in another layout. the login and retreival of information runs in one activity. and as you can see when the login is success it launches the intentResult and pass's some data through extra's that i omitted.

How can i get the status's to load in a list on the intentResult activity when it is launched?

Answer (score 0):

Create a ListView on the intentResult Activity and use an ArrayAdapter to link to your List of status'.

That's supposing you pass a List as extra to the intentResult activity.

How to convert List to ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Status s : statusList) {
     stringList.add(s.toString());
}

intentResult.putExtra("status_list", stringList);
startActivity(intentResult);
```

Comment: Supposing intentResult is an Intent variable, just use this: intentResult.putExtra("status_list", status);

Comment: But will it load correctly into a list? Or will it just load a s a string?

Comment: Yes, as long as the List<??> is a Serializable object it will pass to the other activity as a list. Then you can use getIntent().getExtra("status_list") on the Activity to retrieve the data.

Comment: It wont accept this   intentResult.putExtra(pkg+".myStatus", status); gives me an syntax error at status....

Comment: Probably that's because `Status` isn't serializable. Can you pass along just the Strings of the Status or do you need the whole Status object?

Comment: I could pass them along as strings..But will it populate correctly for each item in a seperate list item for each status?

Comment: Yes. Just create an ArrayList<String> with all the status as strings on the arraylist and pass the ArrayList as I told you.

Comment: OK, done. Hope it helps. I'm not sure about the `s.toString()` method 'cause I don't know the API